# pycharm why there is this run configuration suggestion?

Tags: pycharm

run configuration on Pycharm

why is there this run configuration suggestion is displayed?

[image: run configuration]]

Any idea about this?

Comment: That configuration is not a template and isn't default, either you or some 3rd party application added it. Also, this question has a problem, it's essential information is added as an image consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), (also it's not clearly [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: It's also not clear what PyCharm version you are using, there have been changes to the *"save run configuration"* dialogue.